# lightdm problem with laptop having Intel and NVidia cards

Tags: nvidia, graphics, lightdm

I've got a new laptop (MSI GP62-7QF) fitted with a Core i5 with its Intel GPU and an Nvidia GTX960M GPu with the Prime switching behavior. 
It took me time to have everything (almost) working on this machine. But something puzzles me a lot. 
I cannot boot the machine with the Intel GPU selected. 
The boot freezes at the massages :

`Starting  LightDisplay Manager
OK Started Light DM Display manager`
And the systems is unresponsive. I have to turn it off with the power button. 
On the contrary, if the Prime selection is set to use the nvidia card, everything boots fine I can  log in and I can *also* switch to Intel GPU by login out and in again !
So all help will be vastly appreciated !
Many thanks in advance for your help.